# json date format using angular javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying  to display json data the html table. When i run my file, date appear as '2018-11-21T00:00:00.000+0000' in my table. But i need to display only
'2018-11-21'. how i do it? can u help my to split it.

```js
import { Certificate } from './certificate';

export const CERTIFICATES: Certificate[] = [
    { date: '2018-11-21T00:00:00.000+0000', ident: 'Fe', moy_certified: 0.297 },
    { date: '2018-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000', ident: 'Cu', moy_certified: 0.04 },
    { date: '2018-11-23T00:00:00.000+0000', ident: 'Mn', moy_certified: 0.0374 }, 
    { date: '2018-11-24T00:00:00.000+0000', ident: 'V', moy_certified: 0.019 },
    { date: '2018-11-25T00:00:00.000+0000', ident: 'Mn', moy_certified: 0.037 }
];
```

```html
<ul class="cert-result">
    <li *ngFor="let certificate of certificates">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Element</th>
          <th>Composition</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{certificate.date}}</td>
          <td>{{certificate.ident}}</td>
          <td>{{certificate.moy_certifiee}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `{{certificate.date | date}}` use `date` filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) (`|`):

> Introducing Angular pipes, a way to write display-value transformations that you can declare in your HTML.
>
> A pipe takes in data as input and transforms it to a desired output.

Change

```
<td>{{certificate.date}}</td>
```

To

```
<td>{{certificate.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun... thank you for answer. now i need to add this my angular material table with expandable feature. but i am troubling . because all data coming with single row. how i modify json data in selected column. please check below link

angular material table with expandable feature
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kavsfy-xrwmuv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Comment: @user1177842, I will request you to ask another question with the specific tags as  I am not that much familiar with *angular material ui*......hope you understands......thanks.

Comment: yes i tried. but stackoverflow site blocked it till 90 days. that is why i asked

Answer (score 1):

2 options for you:

1. You can use Angular filter by date https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date
2. `(new Date(certificate.date)).toLocaleDateString()`;